# Spivak Calculus on Manifolds - Problem 2.26 (a)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Problem 2.26 Let $f(x) = e^{-(x-1)^{-2}} \cdot e^{-(x+1)^{-2}}$ for $x \in (-1,1)$ and $f(x) = 0, x \notin (-1,1)$
>
> (a) Show that $f: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a $C^{\infty}$ function which is positive on (-1,1) and $0$ elsewhere.

Hi guys, I know that this function is $C^{\infty}$ in $(-1,1)$ because is just use the chain rule and note that $f = 0$ for $x < -1$ or $x > 1$, but my doubt is how to prove that $f$ is $C^{\infty}$ in $-1$ and $1$. I tried computing the lateral limits on $-1$ and on $1$, but I couldn't, can someone help me prove that $f$ is $C^{\infty}$ in $-1$ and $1$? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to prove that the function $f(x) = e^{-1/x^2}$ for $x > 0$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $x \le 0$ is $C^\infty$-smooth on $\mathbb R$ since your function is just translates and products of this function. Here the only questionable point is $x = 0$. From the left, it is clear that $f^{(n)}(0^-) = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. We just need to prove that the same thing holds from the right. For $x > 0$, we have \begin{align*}
f'(x) &= \frac{2}{x^3} e^{-1/x^2},\\
f''(x) &= \bigg( \frac{4}{x^6} - \frac{6}{x^4}\bigg) e^{-1/x^2}, \\
&\,\,\,\,\,\vdots \\
f^{(n)}(x) &= p_n(1/x)e^{-1/x^2}
\end{align*} for some polynomial $p_n$. In order to conclude, we need to show that $$\lim_{x \to 0^+} p_n(1/x) e^{-1/x^2} = 0, \,\,\,\,\,\, \forall n \in \mathbb N.$$It suffices to show that $$\lim_{x \to 0^+} p(1/x) e^{-1/x^2} = 0$$ for any polynomial $p$. Indeed, we see that $$\lim_{x \to 0^+} p(1/x) e^{-1/x^2} = \lim_{x \to +\infty} p(x) e^{-x^2} = 0$$ where, in the lase step, you can just repeatedly use l'Hopital's rule.

Comment: I understood, thanks a lot! For a long time I was trying understand why it is true and every place that I read about this exercise the people simply said that reason it is obvious and don't explain why! I am really grateful for your help!

Comment: @George Glad I could help!